# POST for a dynamic PDF in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I would like to use jQuery to `POST` for a dynamically generated PDF and display it on the same page.

I have successfully been able to POST the data to a PDF generating script (PHP), create a randomly named PDF file, and return that for jQuery to put into an `<object></object>` however that generates two requests.  I also don't want to have jquery set an `<object>` src to `generate.php?data=DATA_HERE` due to the fact that there is a lot of data and I would rather `POST`

I would like to fetch the binary PDF data with jQuery and embed it into the DOM.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can use an iframe I guess. Changing its source with Jquery.

Comment: How?  That leads me to the exact same issue with changing the object SRC.  I don't want to have to do src="genpdf.php?data=DATA_HERE".  That is ugly looking.

Comment: How do you want to display on a page without using an Iframe or <object> tag (which is uglier than Iframe) ?

Comment: Maybe you can look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html